# Golang - why do compilations on similar machines result in significantly different binary file sizes?

Tags: go, operating-system, binaryfiles, gorilla

I have a gorilla/mux based web service written in Golang.
I've observed that the exact same code produces a binary of size more than 10 MB on my Windows 10 Pro Machine while its about 7 MB on my colleague's Windows 10 Pro Machine.
On yet another colleague's MacBook Pro running OS X Yosemite, the binary is just a bit over 11 MB in size.
What does this binary actually contain?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may be due to different architectures (`GOARCH` env variable). Run `go env` to verify. Compiled binary to `386` and to `amd64` differs significantly (compiled to `amd64` is significantly bigger), but it should be close if the architecture is the same with different OS.

Also the Go version itself matters a lot, Go 1.7 reduced the compiled binary size. See blog post [Smaller Go 1.7 binaries](https://blog.golang.org/go1.7-binary-size) for details.

Also I assume it's the same, but whether debug info is excluded can reduce the compiled binary size significantly.

Comment: Thank you for analysis! I guess its the debug info part, but I will investigate and see what it is.